# How can I change this shader so the rings can be displayed on a transparent surface?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I need a transparent plane, on which a sonar-like effect is displayed.

I already tried adapting the code from the Unity shader tutorial on [transparent shaders](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/making-transparent-shader) in various ways, but it didn't work out.

```cs
Shader "MadeByProfessorOakie/SimpleSonarShader" {
    Properties{
        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _RingColor("Ring Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _RingColorIntensity("Ring Color Intensity", float) = 2
        _RingSpeed("Ring Speed", float) = 1
        _RingWidth("Ring Width", float) = 0.1
        _RingIntensityScale("Ring Range", float) = 1
        _RingTex("Ring Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader{
        Tags{ "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _RingTex;


        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float3 worldPos;
            float3 uv_Illum;
        };

        // The size of these arrays is the number of rings that can be rendered at once.
        // If you want to change this, you must also change QueueSize in SimpleSonarShader_Parent.cs
        half4 _hitPts[20];
        half _StartTime;
        half _Intensity[20];

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;
        fixed4 _RingColor;
        // 追加
        fixed4 _EmissionLM;
        half _RingColorIntensity;
        half _RingSpeed;
        half _RingWidth;
        half _RingIntensityScale;


        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;

            half DiffFromRingCol = abs(o.Albedo.r - _RingColor.r) + abs(o.Albedo.b - _RingColor.b) + abs(o.Albedo.g - _RingColor.g);


            // Check every point in the array
            // The goal is to set RGB to highest possible values based on current sonar rings
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

                half d = distance(_hitPts[i], IN.worldPos);
                half intensity = _Intensity[i] * _RingIntensityScale;
                half val = (1 - (d / intensity));

                if (d < (_Time.y - _hitPts[i].w) * _RingSpeed && d >(_Time.y - _hitPts[i].w) * _RingSpeed - _RingWidth && val > 0) {
                    half posInRing = (d - ((_Time.y - _hitPts[i].w) * _RingSpeed - _RingWidth)) / _RingWidth;

                    // Calculate predicted RGB values sampling the texture radially
                    float angle = acos(dot(normalize(IN.worldPos - _hitPts[i]), float3(1,0,0)));
                    val *= tex2D(_RingTex, half2(1 - posInRing, angle));
                    half3 tmp = _RingColor * val + c * (1 - val);

                    // Determine if predicted values will be closer to the Ring color
                    half tempDiffFromRingCol = abs(tmp.r - _RingColor.r) + abs(tmp.b - _RingColor.b) + abs(tmp.g - _RingColor.g);
                    if (tempDiffFromRingCol < DiffFromRingCol)
                    {
                        // Update values using our predicted ones.
                        DiffFromRingCol = tempDiffFromRingCol;
                        o.Albedo.r = tmp.r;
                        o.Albedo.g = tmp.g;
                        o.Albedo.b = tmp.b;
                        o.Albedo.rgb *= _RingColorIntensity;
                    }
                }
            }

            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
        }

        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

I guess I have to use something else than the surf method. When I change the _Color value of the corresponding Material the Shader is applied to in the editor to transparent, the plane is still visible.

Changing 
`#pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows`
to 
`#pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows alpha:fade`
Makes the plane transparent, but the circles aren't visible either.

Comment: Do you really need this to be a shader ? I would suggest looking at the new particle system, it could easily answer your need. If you really want to use a shader, do it with the Shader graph, it's WAY easier than diving directly into shader code

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
#pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows
```

To this:

```
#pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows alpha:fade
```

From the [unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaders.html):

> Transparency can typically be of two kinds: traditional alpha blending
>   (used for fading objects out) or more physically plausible
>   “premultiplied blending” (which allows semitransparent surfaces to
>   retain proper specular reflections).
>
> - alpha or alpha:auto - Will pick fade-transparency (same as alpha:fade) for simple lighting functions, and premultiplied *
>     transparency (same as alpha:premul) for physically based lighting
>     functions.
> - alpha:blend - Enable alpha blending.
> - alpha:fade - Enable traditional fade-transparency.
> - alpha:premul - Enable premultiplied alpha transparency.